# How to remove Content-Type and User-Agent headers from HttpClient request?

Tags: http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create Http request using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in xamarin (target: .net standard) environment. Requests will be periodic and won't contain much data. By default all requests contain `User-Agent` and `Content-Type` headers, which are 4 times larger than request's body.
I don't need `Content-Type` because server accepts only one content-type and it assumes the proper one when header is not present.

I've already tried removing UserAgent header, but then the default one is still being set.

```cs
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Clear();
```

I also tried setting Content-Type to null, empty string, etc:

```cs
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = null; //Doesn't work
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(null); //Throws exception
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(""); //Throws exception
```

How can I create awaitable http request and have full control over headers?

Answer (score 1):

After day of struggle I found out, that Xamarin can use two different implementations of `HttpMessageHandler` which is underlying mechanism which actually sends request:

- Managed (the older one) - sends headers like expected (empty `User-Agent` and `Content-Type` are not being sent.
- Native - is default one, and behaves like in the question.

`HttpClient` in .NET Core behaves like managed one, so I assume this is the expected behavior.
Issue on github: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2747

Sources:

- https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs#L68
- https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack